# Tilde operator as function parameter

Tags: r, plotly

I saw [this example of plotly](https://plotly.com/r/animations/), and I wonder how the tilde (~) thing work:

```
plot_ly(
    x = ~gdpPercap, 
    y = ~lifeExp, 
    size = ~pop, 
    color = ~continent, 
    frame = ~year, 
    text = ~country, 
    hoverinfo = "text",
    type = 'scatter',
    mode = 'markers'
)
```

I mean I get what it does (selecting the column of the same name in the dataframe), but what does this operator actually do? What is the nature of the identifier after the tilde (it’s not a variable, not a litteral, …)? Is it specific to plotly?
I saw documentation about the tilde operator in R, but it doesn’t seem related to this specific use.
And finally what is the syntax if the name of the column in the dataframe contains characters such as '-' or '/'?

Comment: The tilde operator is a little over-(ab)used, in my opinion, though they are all similar in a sense. (1) In base R, it is used to create a `formula` that, among other things, tends to include the calling environment; this can be used for (e.g.) definition/extraction of the model matrix. (2) In `rlang`/`purrr`, it is used as a code-golf shortened anonymous function of sorts, where `function(z) z*2` --> `~ .x*2` or just `~ .*2`. (3) In plotly, it is being used to declare the variable to be used, but in a NSE-way. (There might be more to it than that, otherwise it seems little-value-added to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @r2evans said in a comment, it is used to create a formula.  That's a quick way to do two things:  record a bit of R language without evaluating it, and associate the environment where it was created with the result.

The differences between things are how functions where it is used make use of the formula object.  For example, the `lm()` function in base R says that expressions to the left of the tilde are treated as responses, and those to the right encode explanatory variables.

The reason `plot_ly` uses it is so that the names it is using (`gdpPercap`, etc.) do not need to be variables visible in the current global environment, they can be columns taken from the `data` argument.  That argument comes first, so with pipes you can say things like

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:10)
b <- rnorm(10)
df %>% plot_ly(x = ~a, y = ~b)   # incomplete example...
```

and it can look up `a` in `df` and `b` in the global environment.

As to your final question, you can put non-syntactic names in backticks, e.g.

```
`a/b` <- 3
`a/b`
# [1] 3
```